# Perl 6 to show index while looping through a list

Tags: raku

When looping through a list (or an array), is there a way to know the index of the current element inside the loop?

Of course, the problem can be solved by looping through indices:

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;
say "$_\t@aa[$_]" for 0 ..^ @aa.elems;
```

But maybe something like the following is possible (I marked with `.CURRENT_INDEX` the method I'm looking for)?

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;
say $_.CURRENT_INDEX\t$_ for @aa;
```

Comment: Try this: `for @aa.kv -> $i, $_ { say "$i: $_" }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR:** Use `.kv` or `.pairs`.

---

This is sort of what is really happening under the hood:

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;

my \iterator = @aa.iterator;

while ($_ := iterator.pull-one) !=:= IterationEnd {
  say $_
}
```

The value in `iterator` in this case is an anonymous class that does the [Iterator](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator) role.

An [Iterator](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator) may or may not have any way to know how many values it has produced. For example the [Iterator](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator) for `.roll(*)` doesn't need to know how many values it has produced so far, so it doesn't.

---

It is possible for an [Iterator](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Iterator) to implement a method that returns its current index.

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;

my \iterator = class :: does Iterator {
  has $.index = 0;     # declares it as public (creates a method)
  has @.values;

  method pull-one () {
    return IterationEnd unless @!values;

    ++$!index;         # this is not needed in most uses of an Iterator
    shift @!values;
  }
}.new( values => @aa );

say "{iterator.index}\t$_" for Seq.new: iterator;
```

```
1   8
2   9
3   10
4   11
5   12
```

You could also do it in a higher level construct;

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;

my $index = 0;
my $seq := gather for @aa { ++$index; take $_ };

say "$index\t$_" for $seq;
```

---

To get `$_.CURRENT-INDEX` to work requires wrapping the result.

```perl6
class Iterator-Indexer does Iterator {
  has Iterator $.iterator is required;
  has $!index = 0;

  method pull-one () {
    my \current-value = $!iterator.pull-one;

    # make sure it ends properly
    return IterationEnd if current-value =:= IterationEnd;

    # element wrapper class
    class :: {
      has $.CURRENT-INDEX;
      has $.value;

      # should have a lot more coercion methods to work properly
      method Str () { $!value }

    }.new( CURRENT-INDEX => $!index++, value => current-value )
  }
}

multi sub with-index ( Iterator \iter ){
  Seq.new: Iterator-Indexer.new: iterator => iter;
}
multi sub with-index ( Iterable \iter ){
  Seq.new: Iterator-Indexer.new: iterator => iter.iterator;
}


my @aa = 8 .. 12;
say "$_.CURRENT-INDEX()\t$_" for with-index @aa.iterator;
# note that $_ is an instance of the anonymous wrapper class
```

---

Again with a higher level construct:

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;

my \sequence := @aa.kv.map: -> $index, $_ {
  # note that this doesn't close over the current value in $index
  $_ but role { method CURRENT-INDEX () { $index }}
}

say "$_.CURRENT-INDEX()\t$_" for sequence;
```

---

I would argue that you should just use `.pairs` if you want it something like this. (or use `.kv` but that basically requires using the block form of `for` with two parameters)

```perl6
my @aa = 8 .. 12;
say "$_.key()\t$_.value()" for @aa.pairs;
```

Comment: Brad Gilbert, thanks you so much the explanation!! And yes, `.pairs` is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 8):

To get the loop index of the current element of loop over a list, you can use the [`.kv`](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/kv) method of a list. It returns an interleaved sequence of indexes and values:

```
my @aa = 8 .. 12;
for @aa.kv -> $i, $_ { say "$i: $_" }
```

**Output**:

```
0: 8
1: 9
2: 10
3: 11
4: 12
```

Comment: Thanks, it's more elegant! But it's nevertheless iteration through $i, which is the index of the list...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, using your own index variable:

```perl6
my @aa = 8..12;
say $++, ": $_" for @aa;
```

**Output:**

```
0: 8
1: 9
2: 10
3: 11
4: 12
```

Comment: But making a counter is basically the same as looping through indices.

Comment: Yes! You know, TMTOWTDI.